# Data Importer Module not working with PowerShell Extensions

Tags: powershell-extensions

I was trying to use the Data Importer to import a csv of data templates.  I get the following error:

```
New-Item : The type is not a known type for the file system. Only "file","directory" or "symboliclink" can be specified.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a known bug and was reported with issue [1152](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1152). Scheduled to be released with SPE 6.1.

The quickest way to get a fix is to apply the following changes to the script:

`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Tools/Data Management/Toolbox/Data Management/Data Importer`

```powershell
#Old Value
$itemPath = "$($destinationNode.ItemPath)/$($row.Name)"

#New Value
$itemPath = "$($destinationNode.ProviderPath)\$($row.Name)"
```

Alternatively, you can copy all of the script from the yml on the master branch as it addresses some other issues as well.

Comment: This worked great the only issue now is on import only the name field takes data.  Am I missing anything here.

Comment: There is an issue with mapping to the template.

Comment: If possible please submit an issue here with steps to reproduce. https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues

Comment: Thank you Michael I have submitted 1165.